# How to enforce a first-page style in a documentclass?

Tags: documentclass-writing

I've written a documentclass in which I've defined a `\fancypagestyle` from `fancyhdr` for the first page.  But the user of my documentclass needs to call `\thispagestyle{firstpagestyle}` in order for this special page style to take effect.

How can I make the documentclass apply the special first page style automatically (with requiring intervention by the documentclass user)?

MWE:

```latex
% myclass.cls

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[v1.0]
\LoadClass[12pt]{article}

% no options yet
\DeclareOption*{\OptionNotUsed}
\ProcessOptions\relax

% header
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{Center header}
\fancypagestyle{firstpagestyle}{
    \fancyhead[C]{First page center header}
}
```

```latex
% main.tex

\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firstpagestyle}  % how to refactor this into myclass.cls?

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add it in the definition of abstract or title

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the one time hook `begindocument/end`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[v1.0]
\LoadClass[12pt]{article}

% no options yet
\DeclareOption*{\OptionNotUsed}
\ProcessOptions\relax

% header
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{Center header}
\fancypagestyle{firstpagestyle}{
    \fancyhead[C]{First page center header}
}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\thispagestyle{firstpagestyle}}
```

Your document:

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]